# Как в поле представления ограничить введение максимального числа?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

У пользователя есть монеты. Их количество в поле не должно превышать их количество в базе данных.

coin.cshtml:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.coin)
```

Монеты пользователя заданы в бд (значение coin пользователя могу получить в контроллере CoinController)

```
public class Coin
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double coins { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не поверите, но [RangeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Этим ограничится максимально возможное число модели. Но у пользователя может быть меньшее число.

Comment: @codename0082016 Почему? Максимум и минимум задается, если я вас правильно понимаю. Или вы хотите в рантайме ограничение вычислять? В этом случае вам нужен кастомный байндер модели, который будет добавлять ошибку состояния модели в случае чего.

Comment: @codename0082016 А вообще, это уже бизнес-правило, которое должно проверяться на уровне бизнес-логики (бэкенда как минимум, но и на фронте можно).